# Complex 4 linked tables MYSQL query

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I have a complex query to write (at least for me).
I have 4 tables
 - **ressources_department** (ressource_record_id, account_id, department_id, active)
 - **ressources_type_users** (id, email, password)
 - **ressources_records** (id,ressource_main_id, ressource_id, account_id)
 - **ressources_records_details** (ressource_record_id,ressource_field_id, ressource_data)

- ressource_department holds the users (ressources_records) for a specific department and account.
- ressource_type_users holds the basic infos for the users (email, password) and his unique id.
- ressource_records holds the users unique id (ressource_main_id) and is also the link to the user details (ressources_records_details)
- ressources_records_details holds the user datas. Ressource_fields (int) is the type of ressource_date. Ex. : 113 is the code for the email address.

I have to write a query to show all the infos inlined.

What I have done so far is :

```
SELECT a.ressource_record_id, a.account_id, a.active, a.department_id, b.ressource_main_id, b.ressource_id 
FROM ressources_department a 
join ressources_records b on a.ressource_record_id = b.id
WHERE a.active=1
```

This give me almost what I need except the ‘ressources_records_details’ datas. I can loop trough php and query the database for each rows but I don’t think it is the way to go.

I tried :

```
SELECT a.ressource_record_id, a.account_id, a.active, a.department_id, b.ressource_main_id, b.ressource_id, max(if((c.ressource_type = 113),c.ressource_data,NULL)) AS email
FROM ressources_department a 
join ressources_records b on a.ressource_record_id = b.id
join ressources_records_details c on a.ressource_record_id = c.ressource_record_id 
group by c.ressource_record_id
```

But some records are missing ... need help, I’m stuck.
Thx!

UPDATE :
I get the results I want with tons of sub-queries but this costs a lot of server time isn't?

```
SELECT a.ressource_record_id, a.account_id, a.active, a.department_id, b.ressource_main_id, b.ressource_id,
(select ressource_data from ressources_records_details where ressource_record_id=a.ressource_record_id and ressource_type=113) as email,
(select ressource_data from ressources_records_details where ressource_record_id=a.ressource_record_id and ressource_type=101) as lastname,
(select ressource_data from ressources_records_details where ressource_record_id=a.ressource_record_id and ressource_type=100) as firstname,
(select ressource_data from ressources_records_details where ressource_record_id=a.ressource_record_id and ressource_type=114) as address,
(select ressource_data from ressources_records_details where ressource_record_id=a.ressource_record_id and ressource_type=115) as zip,
(select ressource_data from ressources_records_details where ressource_record_id=a.ressource_record_id and ressource_type=116) as city
FROM ressources_department a 
join ressources_records b on a.ressource_record_id = b.id
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample, your actual result and the expected  result

Comment: Yes. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without subqueries by using `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT rd.ressource_record_id, rd.account_id, rd.active, 
    rd.department_id, rr.ressource_main_id, rr.ressource_id,
CASE WHEN rrd.resource_type = 113 THEN ressource_data ELSE NULL END AS email,
CASE WHEN rrd.resource_type = 101 THEN ressource_data ELSE NULL END AS lastname,
CASE WHEN rrd.resource_type = 100 THEN ressource_data ELSE NULL END AS firstname,
CASE WHEN rrd.resource_type = 114 THEN ressource_data ELSE NULL END AS address,
CASE WHEN rrd.resource_type = 115 THEN ressource_data ELSE NULL END AS zip,
CASE WHEN rrd.resource_type = 116 THEN ressource_data ELSE NULL END AS city
FROM ressources_department rd 
JOIN ressources_records rr 
    ON rb.ressource_record_id = rr.id
JOIN ressources_records_details rrd 
    ON rrd.ressource_record_id = rd.ressource_record_id
GROUP BY rd.ressource_record_id, rd.account_id, 
    rd.active, rd.department_id, rr.ressource_main_id, rr.ressource_id
```